# Bamboo does not want to create Artifacts

Tags: bamboo

During build with Bamboo we creating file `/var/atlassian/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/T4-TGDP-RD/release/dev_patch_release.tar.bz2`. This file exist, checked it with command line.

At 'Artifact definitions' I have following pattern: `**/release/*.bz2`.

But unfortunately after build is done, in Bamboo -> Build -> Artifact `No artifacts have been found for this build result.`.

In the same time, I have unit tests with result at `**/extra/build/logs/*.xml` that successfully parsed by JUnit.

So, I also created another artifact pattern with `**/extra/build/logs/*.xml` - still Bamboo does not see it, but JUnit parse it.

How do I create an artifact `dev_patch_release.tar.bz2` with Bamboo?

Bamboo build Log:

```
simple      08-May-2014 23:11:33    Build Dev Patch - Release and Deploy #17 (T4-TGDP-RD-17) started building on agent Agent2
simple  08-May-2014 23:11:33    Build working directory is /var/atlassian/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/T4-TGDP-RD
simple  08-May-2014 23:11:33    Executing build Dev Patch - Release and Deploy #17 (T4-TGDP-RD-17)
simple  08-May-2014 23:11:33    Starting task 'Source Code Checkout' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.vcs:task.vcs.checkout'    simple  08-May-2014 23:11:33    Updating source code to revision: c100a20080b08f79b6d1f566dc55a1f5154ff069
simple  08-May-2014 23:11:37    Updated source code to revision: c100a20080b08f79b6d1f566dc55a1f5154ff069
simple  08-May-2014 23:11:37    Finished task 'Source Code Checkout'
simple  08-May-2014 23:11:37    Running pre-build action: Clover Grails PreBuild Action
simple  08-May-2014 23:11:37    Running pre-build action: VCS Version Collector
command 08-May-2014 23:11:37    Substituting variable: ${bamboo.build.working.directory} with /var/atlassian/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/T4-TGDP-RD    command 08-May-2014 23:11:37    Substituting variable: ${bamboo.buildResultKey} with T4-TGDP-RD-17
command 08-May-2014 23:11:37    Substituting variable: ${bamboo.repository.revision.number} with c100a20080b08f79b6d1f566dc55a1f5154ff069
simple  08-May-2014 23:11:37    Starting task 'Run Phing' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.scripttask:task.builder.command'
command 08-May-2014 23:11:37    Beginning to execute external process for build 'Dev Patch - Release and Deploy #17 (T4-TGDP-RD-17)'\n ... running command line: \n/usr/bin/phing -buildfile /var/atlassian/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/T4-TGDP-RD/bamboo-dev-patch.xml test\n ... in: /var/atlassian/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/T4-TGDP-RD\n ... using extra environment variables: \nrevision=c100a20080b08f79b6d1f566dc55a1f5154ff069\nbuild_result_key=T4-TGDP-RD-17\n
build   08-May-2014 23:11:39    [00;36mBuildfile: /var/atlassian/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/T4-TGDP-RD/bamboo-dev-patch.xml[0m
build   08-May-2014 23:11:39    [00;32m
build   08-May-2014 23:11:39    Dev Patch Build Plan > prepare:
build   08-May-2014 23:11:39    [0m
build   08-May-2014 23:11:39    [00;36m    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/atlassian/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/T4-TGDP-RD/release[0m
build   08-May-2014 23:12:05    Dev Patch Build Plan > test:
build   08-May-2014 23:12:05    [0m
build   08-May-2014 23:12:05    [00;36m     [echo] tar cfj /var/atlassian/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/T4-TGDP-RD/release/dev_patch_release.tar.bz2 ./[0m
build   08-May-2014 23:12:48    [00;32m
build   08-May-2014 23:12:48    BUILD FINISHED
build   08-May-2014 23:12:48    
build   08-May-2014 23:12:48    Total time: 1 minutes  9.67 seconds
build   08-May-2014 23:12:48    [0m
simple  08-May-2014 23:12:48    Finished task 'Run Phing'
simple  08-May-2014 23:12:48    Running post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
simple  08-May-2014 23:12:48    Running post build plugin 'Clover Results Collector'
simple  08-May-2014 23:12:48    Finalising the build...
simple  08-May-2014 23:12:48    Stopping timer.
simple  08-May-2014 23:12:48    Build T4-TGDP-RD-17 completed.
simple  08-May-2014 23:12:48    Running on server: post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
simple  08-May-2014 23:12:48    Running on server: post build plugin 'Clover Delta Calculator'
simple  08-May-2014 23:12:48    All post build plugins have finished
simple  08-May-2014 23:12:48    Generating build results summary...
simple  08-May-2014 23:12:48    Saving build results to disk...
simple  08-May-2014 23:12:48    Indexing build results...
simple  08-May-2014 23:12:48    Finished building T4-TGDP-RD-17.
```

Comment: Is /var/atlassian/bamboo/your bamboo root folder?

Comment: `/var/atlassian/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/T4-TGDP-RD` - Build working directory. And yes, `/var/atlassian/bamboo/` it's bamboo's root folder.

Comment: The build log is interesting. I don't see it ran the Artifact copier post build plugin.  This is an example for my build log:


`simple 06-May-2014 11:07:00 Running post build plugin 'Artifact Copier'
simple 06-May-2014 11:07:00 Publishing an artifact: All`

I don't think there is such option to disable creating artifact globally. What version of Bamboo are you using?

Comment: Thanks for help, it was a bug at Bamboo: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-14585

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In artifact definition screen:

For `Location` specify a relative path to the files you want to create artifact
For `Copy pattern`, specify the pattern to be copied.

For you case, put `./release` into the Location box, then specify `*.bz2` as a copy pattern.

For more info, see this issue https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-2149

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering, unfortunately it didn't help. I have feeling that you can some how on global level switch off Artefact creation and thats why it does not work. I attached Bamboo build log to the question's description, maybe it could help.

Comment: and yes, after I fixed problem with publishing Artifacts, your solution is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

CW answer migrated from the question:

> Due to the bug `Shutting down Bamboo while builds are still running
>   causes plugins (i.e. Artifact copier plugin) disabling`
>   (https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-14585) Bamboo's system plugin
>   "System Builders" could be disabled, so it stop publishing artifacts.
>
> In comments to the bug you can find solution:
>
> 1. Go to Administration -> Manage add-ons
> 2. Select "System" from the filter drop down
> 3. Find the plugin "System Builders"
> 4. Enable it!
>
> My version of Bamboo where bug is still appears: `5.4.1 build 4207 -
>   12 Feb 14`.
>
> Related question at Atlassian answers website:
>   https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/292548/bamboo-does-not-want-to-create-artifacts
>
> Atlassian will soon release patch to fix this problem.